# Carthrob price modifier wont show price in cart

Tags: cartthrob

I am using Carthrob with the price modifiers fieldtype.

In the add to cart form everything works as it should. However, when I add an item to the cart, I can't get the price to display, and the cart total is all out of wack.

I have done a variety of tests but can't figure out the issue. Can anyone take a look at the following code and see if I am missing something really obvious?

I have the following code for my add to cart form:

```
{exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form return="enter/checkout"}

    {exp:cartthrob:item_options entry_id="{entry_id}" }
        {select id="purchase-submissions-select" class="standard required"}
            <option {selected} value="{option_value}">{option_name} {price}</option>
        {/select}
    {/exp:cartthrob:item_options}

    <input id="purchase-submissions-submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />

{/exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form}
```

and this as a test in my cart:

```
{exp:cartthrob:update_cart_form return="/index.php/basket/"}
    {exp:cartthrob:cart_items_info}

        {item_option:fees} - {price} - {quantity}<br />

        {if last_row}
            {cart_total}
        {/if}

    {/exp:cartthrob:cart_items_info}
{/exp:cartthrob:update_cart_form}
```

P.S I have seen the other thread with a similar problem, and have checked and its not the same issue (i.e no dollar symbols in with the price).

Thank you.

Comment: I doubt it'll fix it, but it can't hurt. Every example I've seen has `cart_items_info` on the outside of `update_cart_form`. Maybe try swapping them.

Comment: Also, in `cart_items_info`. You should use `{item_price}` instead of `{price}`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got your cookies set up in admin/config? I've been going through a similar issue.

Also, check to see if your server I've and computer time are pretty close. It old be that your sessions are a bit lost.

I ran through these:
http://cartthrob.com/docs/pages/troubleshooting/#add-to-cart-problems

You may well have seen this already.

Are ou using msm at all? Or Stash?

Lastly, it's a long shot, but add parse="inward" on your item_options. It could be that it's not parsing right.